# how to find out if a sharepoint list is created by end-user or created as part of site provisioning

Tags: sharepoint-2010, splist

I would like to find out whether a sharepoint list is created by end-user or created as part of site provisioning.

I want to show all lists created by end user into a dropdown. I could filter on template id = 100 but there are some system generated lists having templateId=100 and they end up in the dropdown list.

Comment: Maybe you should exclude system lists from dropdown and not lists created during provisioning? Because user could use lists created during provisioning.

Comment: yes; user can use lists created during provisioning; but user will most likely be creating his own lists rather than re-using provisioned lists (this is part of use-case for the drop-down list)

Comment: i am afraid that there is no way to know if list was created during provisioning. Maybe you can get some useful information from audit log(SPList.Audit)

Answer (score 0):

The SPList object does contain a Created property and the containing SPWeb does as well. Note that you won't be able to do a direct comparison because presumably it took many seconds (or even longer) to provision your site but if you did a fuzzy comparison of those two dates you should be able to separate user created vs. system provisioned lists.